# Read data from existing SQLite database through ionic and angular

Tags: angular, sqlite, ionic-framework

I'm new to ionic app development.
Going to develop a dictionary app with ionic, angular and sqlite.
SQLite db file is already prepared with required tables and the app needs to be deployed with the db file.

As the first step how can I read data from db file?

Should I use
*SQLite* https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite 
or
*SQLite Porter* https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite-porter

```
let db = (<any>window).openDatabase('dictionary', '1.0', 'dictionary', 1 * 1024);
    this.http.get('../assets/database/dictionary.db', { responseType: 'text' })
          .subscribe(sql => {
            this.sqlitePorter.importSqlToDb(db, 'select * from terms')
              .then(() => console.log('Imported'))
              .catch(e => console.error(e));
          }, error => {
            console.log('error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
          });
```

I tried above coding but it gives me 404 not found error on Android Studio emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The import file should be .sql not .db. Since *SqliteDbCopy* is having an copying issue with capacitor, I used *SQLitePorter*

Final solution is to use capacitor, SQLitePorter and .sql file to import data.

Comment: Where you have a supplementary question, please ask that as a new question. Thanks!